# Vue.js, emit multiple parameters from child to parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-events

I am trying to emit multiple parameters from child to parents.What is the best way to do it.

**Child**

```
 getUpdated(value, type) {
                  
    if (type === 'students') {
     this.students = value.map(val => val.id);
    }
                  
    if (type === 'programs') {
     this.programs = value.map(val => val.code);
    }
    this.$emit('selectedOptions', students:this.students, programs:this.programs );
    },
```

**Parent**

```
 onSelectedOption(students, programs) {
    if (students !== undefined || students.length > 1) {
      this.students = students;
  } 
  if (programs !== undefined || programs.length > 1) {
    this.programs = programs;
  }
},
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Emit an object with multiple properties:

```js
this.$emit('selectedOptions', {
  students: this.students,
  programs: this.programs
});
```

And in the parent:

```js
onSelectedOption(options) {
  if (options.students && options.students.length) {
    this.students = options.students;
  } 
  if (options.programs && options.programs.length) {
    this.programs = options.programs;
  }
},
```